# INSERT Flash Object Into MySql with PHP

Tags: mysql, flash, youtube, embed

I'm breaking my head over this.

I'm trying to insert embeddable video code, such as youtube/viddler/etc.. which all start with the object tag:

`<object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ahg6qcgoay4?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ahg6qcgoay4?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object>`

into MySQL with PHP. I've looked all over the internet and there was nothing solid to make that happen. Does anyone know how to INSERT that code successfully to the database as the value for $video?

UPDATE: I figured out how to store it but now, I'm trying to call it in php, but only get the text value back, basically, the entire embed code as text is displayed instead of the video itself. Here is my display code which shows text. How can I make it show the actual video instead?

```
<?php
    //assuming a connection to the database exists
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysql_query( $sql );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {
    $html = array();  //create an array of html formated values.
    $html['video'] = nl2br( stripslashes( htmlentities( $row['video'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) ) );
    echo "Video:<br />{$html['video']}<hr />";
}   ?>
```

**UPDATE:** This is what the embed code looks like in the DB:

```
<object width=\"450\" height=\"380\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/Z5j3CORfxmw&hl=en_US&fs=1&rel=0&color1=0x3a3a3a&color2=0x999999\"></param><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param><param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"></param><embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/Z5j3CORfxmw&hl=en_US&fs=1&rel=0&color1=0x3a3a3a&color2=0x999999\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" width=\"450\" height=\"380\"></embed></object>
```

The php code right above it pulls out this data, without the slashes and it displays the embed code perfectly as text, but the actual video does not form from that. Is there anyway to have the code displayed act as code and show the video instead of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to do this, why not simply save the various parameters values and recreate the embed code in your PHP script?

This would be more flexible & future proof. Let's imagine, for example , that the embed code format is changed next year, you'd have to entirely modify your database records as opposed to updating a single script.

```
//Assuming that you have saved a JSON string in Mysql
$video = json_decode($video_data);

<object width="<? = $video->width;>" height="<? = $video->height;>">
   <param name="movie"    
          value="<? = $video->url;>"></param>
   <param name="allowFullScreen" 
          value="true"></param>
   <param name="allowscriptaccess" 
          value="always"></param>
   <embed src="<? = $video->url;>" 
          type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
          allowscriptaccess="always" 
          allowfullscreen="true" 
          width="<? = $video->width;>" height="<? = $video->height;>"></embed>
 </object>
```

Comment: I was able to get it in with lots of research, and saved it as TEXT. Now that I pull it out, from the table, it only shows the entire thing as text, instead of display the actual video. How can we have the video itself display now in php, instead of the text value for it?

Comment: Same answer as above :) set your embed code with variables, load the vars from Mysql and the video will show! it's still possible to save all this data as a String, simply use JSON.

Comment: I'm actually passing a textarea's value with the embed code via POST to MySQL and saving it as $video. JSON seems too complicated for me to break down the entire textarea result into sections, save them, and then put them back. I'm not too fluent in JSON or any JS, and just started learning MySQL. The issue is also that the text area will not only have youtube, but over 6 embed codes can be put there, and saved to the DB. I won't know how to break all that up and save it part by part for users. I just pasted what the embed code looks like in the DB, is there another simpler way to pull it out?

Answer (score 0):

Inserting this string in the database should be no different than inserting any other string. Just use prepared statements or escape the string properly. When embedding that string on the page however do not escape it as it contains raw HTML code.

In this case though it seems you could simply keep the video id `Ahg6qcgoay4` as the embedding code itself should be the same regardless of the video.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = embed code

echo htmlspecialchars_decode($var);
```